# TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a problem with a string. This is the code:

```
if x.find("Sensor")!=-1 :
```

The error that comes out to me is the following:

```
if x.find("Sensor")!=-1 :
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'
```

I think I need to convert the string to binary.
Do you have any idea how to do it?

Thank you all

Comment: Seems variable `x` contains a byte string object. So, you should pass `x.find(b"Sensor")` byte string as a parameter of the `find` method. Your current condition will work only on a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means your string is a bytes object, so try:

```
if x.find(b"Sensor")!=-1 :
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if you are analyzing a string or a byte object. If it is a byte object you just decode it, example:

```
element = b'Content to be searched'
string_element = element.decode('UTF-8')
string_element.find('word you are looking for')
```